# Delete records from database wit parameters from AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I Have a Stored Procedure that Needs fileID to delete a record from a table.

This is my Table

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="documentsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!--<th>Id</th>-->
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
                <!--<th>SID</th>-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="c in documentsData">
            <!--<td>{{c.fileID}}</td>-->
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{c.contentType}}">{{c.name}}</a></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteDocuments()" value="Delete" /></td>
            <!--<td>{{c.sid}}</td>-->
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I'm not showing FileID here but documentsData contain the File ID

This is my JS

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('portalApp')
        .directive('documentsTable', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: 'app/views/Documents.html',
                controller: function ($scope, apiSvc, $routeParams) {
                    var SID = $routeParams.sid;
                    var getDocuments = function (sid) {
                        return apiSvc.Documents.query({ id: sid });
                    };
                    
                    $scope.documentsData = getDocuments(SID);
                    
                    //Table Row Index
                    $scope.GetRowIndex = function (index) {
                        $window.alert("Row Index: " + index);
                    };

                    //Delete Documents
                    $scope.deleteDocuments = function () {
                        apiSvc.DeleteDocuments.save({ id: $routeParams.sid }, function (error) {
                            console.warn("Unable to Delete Document (" + error + ")");
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
               
                        
        });
        
 })();
```

I have no idea how to pass the fileID for the selected row to my Post

This is my table

[image: My Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using a directive for this, but if that is really what you want to do, I would recommend doing a bit more research on how to implement directives. You are putting the directive name as the element id, but it needs to either be an element name or an attribute name. Having said that, the logic you are handling would be much easier to handle in the controller.

To solve your immediate problem though, you just pass in the fileID to your deleteDocument function.

**.html**

```
// left the rest out for brevity
<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteDocuments(c.fileID)" value="Delete" /></td>
```

**.js**

```
// left the rest out for brevity
//Delete Documents
$scope.deleteDocuments = function (fileID) {
    apiSvc.DeleteDocuments.save({ id: fileID }, function (error) {
        console.warn("Unable to Delete Document (" + error + ")");
    });
}
```